# Spring Batch: How can I define is StepExecution a parent or child step?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I defined `firstStep` which is a parent step. It has various child steps for parallel computation.

```
<step id=“firstStep" next=“secondStep”>
    <partition step=“firstAdditinalStep" partitioner="simplePartitioner">
        <handler grid-size=“${app.conf.threads}" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </partition>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref=“myListener”/>        
    </listeners>
</step>
```

I have entry point which allows me to grab all StepExecution's. And now I need to compare steps and define which StepExecution ia a parent or child step (for all steps). What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't doing anything out of the ordinary, the master's `StepExecution` will be named the same as the step.  The slave's `StepExecution`s are named `<SLAVE_STEP_NAME>:partitionN` where `<SLAVE_STEP_NAME>` is the name of the slave step bean and the last N is the partition number.